# Console Exe generated by CodeBlocks doesn't run under Windows 11?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I downloaded codeblocks 20.03, wrote a simple helloworld program, and tried to run it from the command line in windows 11.  It doesn't print anything, neither does it produce an error message like "DLL not found".  How to fix this problem?

```
    // File: main.cpp
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

from powershell prompt:

```
    PS> cd C:\Users\user1\Desktop\hello\bin\Debug>.\hello.exe
    # Doesn't print anything?

    PS>
```

Runs ok from the codeblocks GUI... but I need to use the exe from the command line eventually.

Here's my directory structure:

```
    C:\Users\user1\Desktop\hello> wsl
    $ find
    .
    ./bin
    ./bin/Debug
    ./bin/Debug/hello.exe
    ./hello.cbp
    ./main.cpp
    ./obj
    ./obj/Debug
    ./obj/Debug/main.o

    $ cd ./bin/Debug/

    $ ls -ltr hello.exe
    -rwxrwxrwx 1 user1 user1 76554 Nov 27 11:05 hello.exe
```

yeah, I know I could compile this code using WSL... but I need a native windows console application...  I'm using Windows API calls in my real source code...

Comment: what compiler did you set CodeBlocks to use?

Comment: I installed "codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup.exe" which includes a version of mingw that is already configured out of the box...   (http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/binaries/)  Worked fine in Windows 10...

Comment: can you show us a `dir` of the folder in which the executable exists? can you remove that executable then and re-create it?

Comment: ok... i just gave you my dir...

Comment: when you remove the file `hello.exe` and re-build it from code blocks, does it re-appear?

Comment: Interestingly, when I remove hello.exe and rebuild it... now it pops up a messagebox that says: "the code execution cannot proceed because libstdc++6.dll was not found.  Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."  Previously,,, it just did nothing and returned to the prompt.

Comment: maybe codeblocks get messed up by upgrading to windows 11?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11 just has trouble locating the DLL files for codeblock generated EXE.  need to manually copy them there:

```
PS> cd C:\Users\user1\Desktop\hello\bin\Debug>
PS> copy 'C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\*.dll' .
PS> .\hello.exe
Hello World!
```